# Variable in the route's name

Tags: symfony

I'm writing three simple form proccessing functions. They are all the same except for the part after the validation check, so I decided to create kind of a "template" function containing the whole code up to the validation if instruction.

These three functions thus contain only the code responsible for the proper form proccessing.

The template function looks kind of like this:

```
public function templateAction($formName) {
   $form = $this->createForm(new {$formName.'Type'}() new $formName());
   $request = $this->getRequest();
   if($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
      $form->bind($request);
      if($form->valid()) {
         $this->{'set'.$formName}($form);
         return array();
      }
   }
}
```

Now, having `Foo` form, passing its name (Foo) as a parameter, I get the form rendered based just on its name, and corresponding private methods containing that name.

---

**The question is** - how can I use `$this->redirect()` function to call this "template" method and pass the proper parameter?

```
/**
 * @Route("/FooController/Template/{formName}", name="/FooController/Template/{formName}")
 */
```

This does not work - sf throws an error that the route wasn't found...I've also tried some other combinations but none worked...how should I handle this?

---

Is this "templating" form proccessing method o.k.? I've thought it might reducte repetitions, but what if I had one method that is supposed to have different code before the validation part?

---

Also, is there a way to separate form proccessing from the controller, and put it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, route names should be something like: `foocontroller_template` or whatever.

```
/**
 * @Route("/FooController/Template/{formName}", name="/FooController/Template/{formName}")
 */
```

Second of all if you call `->redirect()` method inside a controller, you have to - as a good practice - let router generate route for you, something like

`$this->get('router')->generate('foocontroller_template', array('formName' => 'foobarform'));`

Obviously, in that way, you have to parametrize - and consequently make it dynamic - your action aswell.